# Links stopped opening in new tab on genesis child theme

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, genesis

I have beed developing a Accessible Website child Theme  on the Genesis Framework.

However when adding content and links to pages and posts none of the links open in a new tab even though I have the **target="_blank"** on all of them! any ideas why this is?

Thanks
- Phillip Dews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I don't understand why that is happening to you and that will be default right ? maybe you did something wrong in your past codes or an error cause by a plugins. 
Try to troubleshoot this way

1. Deactivate / Active your theme.
2. Deactivate / Active your plugins.
3. Sort your previous codes

to know about genesis framework, follow me here [anthonycarbon.com](https://www.anthonycarbon.com/)